# Can I create Relative Domain names in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services

I would like to have two virtual hosts (2 projects) on single machine, and would like to have configuration that is independent of domain name this machine/IP is assigned to

For example I have

- Domain name `testDomainName.com` and expecting it to be deployed to `example.com` or `whatever.com`,
- 2 projects `project1` and `project2`.

I'd like to configure `project1.testDomainName.com` and `project2.testDomainName.com`, and don't care if it'll change in the future to `example.com` or `whatever.com`.

In other words, **how can I assign "project1" and "project2" as names, and have the apache automatically cocatenate/interpret it as `project1.whatever.com`, and `project2.whatever.com`**

Comment: Could do something like this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html it's a bit of work but would work just fine for your needs. Or you could just have <VirtualHost> entries for both...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the speed response, but my point is that I don't know what is the value of "example.com". What I want to know is can I, and how avoid using it. I assumed that using <VirtualHosts> is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. What you're looking for is [VirtualDocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) directive.

Comment: Thanks @Marcel. This wasn't approach I expected, but it perfectly solves the issue.  Thanks again.